# SVN Merge, then rebase

Tags: svn, branch, rebase

I am trying to find the proper way to reintegrate the changes in my SVN branch to the trunk, and the rebase.

I have successfully merged my changes from the branch back to the trunk using,

```
  reintegrate merge http://mybranch into C:\code\trunk
```

Now i need to recreate my development branch from the trunk.  What is the best way to do this?

**Backgound**

We basically have a release trunk, and all development goes down in branches until it is time for releases, so the process is merge changes to trunk, release, rebase branch do more changes, repeat process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just commit the changes by the merge and create a new branch from the current trunk

```
svn cp ^/trunk ^/branches/NewBaseLine -m"- New Baseline"
```

What i missed to ask: Why do you need to "--reintegrate" ? Isn't a simple merge enough? Have you merged changes from trunk to branch before?

Comment: i am doing the opposite, basically create a branch from trunk, then merged back up (reintegrate), now i just want to reuse the same branch and continue developing.

Comment: Ah ok...I just want to make clear we are talking about the same, because in SVN merge an option --reintegrate exists which has a different meaning. In your situation you can simply continue working on the branch and later do another merge to the trunk via svn merge ^/branches/BrnachName and that's it.